# same WebResource.axd / ScriptResource.axd for mulltiple applications and CDN

Tags: asp.net, embedded-resource, cdn

Is it possible to force ASP.NET to generate the same hash part of `WebResource.axd / ScriptResource.axd` URL from different web applications?

For example i have `MyControls.dll` that has embedded resource "`control.js`" and it used in two websites: www.site1.com, www.site2.com (MyControls.dll exists in bin folder of both sites).
For each website, ASP.NET generates the WebResource.axd URL with different hash for "control.js".

**Question:** Can I force somehow that it will be the same resource URL for both sites?

Why I need this....? I use "shared" CDN for resources from both websites. It works perfect for all resources except `WebResource.axd / ScriptResource.axd`. When resource requested from www.site2.com, CDN tries to retrieve resource for cache from www.site1.com, but since the hash that arrived from www.site2.com is different, CDN fails to load and cache resource.

Answer (score 0):

You could use asp:ScriptManager to 'unbundle' the resources - much better for proxy caches as they don't tend to cache URLs with querystrings

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="Script" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
  <Scripts>
      <asp:ScriptReference Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions" Path="~/js/ms/MicrosoftAjax.js" >
      <asp:ScriptReference Name="MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions" Path="~/js/ms/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js">
  </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

If you do choose this approach, don't forget to enable gzip and appropriate caching directives.

Comment: I don't know, may be ScriptManager will solve the problem for scripts, but in my case the resources can JS, CSS and images.